# copy file directory with node ncp and minify everything

Tags: node.js, npm, uglifyjs, npm-scripts

I want to have an npm script that:

1. copies a directory and its sub directories with structure intact
2. minifies all the html, css, and js files

I have the copying part working with ncp and node,

```
var ncp = require('ncp').ncp;
ncp.limit = 16;
const options = {
    clobber: true,  //overwrite dir
    stopOnErr: true
}
ncp('src', 'public', options, function(err) {
    if (err){return console.error(err);}
    console.log('copied with node!');
});
```

but how can I apply something like uglify or a regex to minify the files? I don't want to use gulp, just node and npm scripts.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out I can do this all with ncp and html-minifier. html-minifier seems to grab the html, css, and JS files. perfect.

in the terminal:

```
npm install --save ncp
npm install --save html-minifier
```

in my npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "html": "html-minifier --input-dir ./public --output-dir ./public --collapse-whitespace --remove-comments",
    "copy": "ncp ./src ./public --stopOnErr && npm run html"
```

}